# i can't detect the location on mobile phones in my chat app

Tags: android, ios, node.js, express, socket.io

I made a simple chat app and i deployed it to heroku and i was testing it with my mobile phones and with my friends' phones. I have a button for users to send location, it's working on PC but it's not working on any phone. How can i detect the problem? When i click the 'send location' button, it just hangs and nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
 // finding location of the user and sending it to the server
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        socket.emit('sendLocation', {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        }, () => {
            console.log('Location shared!')
            $sendLocationButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: i'm not sure if this question actually has anything to do with android or ios, might just entirely be an issue with express, but i suppose the tags are fine just incase :)

Comment: me neither, as you said, i added them just in case.

Comment: I think you missing the request for permission on phone device

Comment: how can i do that?